# how to print local pdf file to another unit from web page PHP

Tags: php, html, href, local-files

I need to open a local file in another unit (eg F: folder.pdf or a network path eg 55.22.33.33 folder.pdf).
Usually to open a file or use page

```
<a href=”link”> open </a>
```

I also tried:

```
<a href=”file///F:\folder\tfile.pdf”> open </a>
<a href=”file///F:/folder/file.pdf”> open </a>
```

This syntax does not work with local files because the browser blocks it, I think for security reasons.
Is there a way to open them? I should open them to print them.

As an alternative I had thought of copying the file to a server folder and then proceeding to open it

Comment: 1) don't use special quotes, use double quotes (for HTML). 2) use relative-to-site pathing, not file - that won't work for anyone not on your machine

Comment: Also, `file///` is not valid, should be `file:///`

Comment: I get the link to the file from a php function that extracts the file path with glob (). If I do as described the browser returns about: blank # blocked. the problem is not file:/// or / or Only firefox and chrome give this problem, while edge and internet explore open it

Answer (score 0):

Code should as below ,you sould  add the `:` character

```
<a href="file:///F:\folder\tfile.pdf"> open </a>
```

Comment: I get the link to the file from a php function that extracts the file path with glob (). If I do as described the browser returns about: blank # blocked. the problem is not file:/// or / or Only firefox and chrome give this problem, while edge and internet explore open it

Comment: yes, I'm developing an application that runs locally.  for this reason the files to be opened are in local.  in Firefox and Chrome does not open them the browser blocks them for security reasons.

Comment: so the only way is to copy the file to the server and then print the link.  or is there any other solution?